# Редактирование текстового файла произвольного размера в C/C++

Tags: c, c++

Например, файл 1.txt содержит информацию "123456789********" Как убрать звёздочки? В конце должно получиться "123456789".

Как правильно редактировать файл 1.txt, не создавая другой файл?

Answer (score 3):

Откроем два потока (один чтение, другой запись (на update)) на тот же файл. Переписываем поверх символы не равные '*', потом урезаем файл.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  if (ac < 2) {
    printf ("No filename\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  int i = 0, c;
  FILE *in = fopen(av[1],"r"), *out = fopen(av[1],"r+");
  if (in == NULL || out == NULL) {
     perror (av[1]);
     exit(2);
  }
  rewind(out);
  while ((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF) {
    if (c != '*') {
      i++;
      fputc(c,out);
    }
  }
  fclose(in);
  ftruncate(fileno(out),i);
  fclose(out);
}
```

Comment: Уважаемый avp, напишите пожалуйста для особо непонятливых программу сразу готовую для конпилеации. а то я запутался в FILE *in = fopen(av[1],"r"), *out = fopen(av[1],"r+");   и  невьехал как работает ftruncate  (((

Comment: Программа компилировалась gcc в MinGW и Interix. FILE *in = fopen("имя файла","r") открывает связывает переменную in с потоком для чтения. FILE *out = (...,"r+") аналогично для записи в этот же файл. "r+" вообще-то открывает файл как для чтения, так и для записи НЕ УРЕЗАЯ ЕГО ПРИ ОТКРЫТИИ. В некоторых реализациях для перехода к операциям записи требуется seek() (rewind()). В переменной i подсчитывается количество байт, которые записали в файл (не *). ftruncate() (см. man 2 ftruncate) урезает файл до нужного размера. Она требует файловый дескриптор, получаем его по fileno(out). Все !

Answer (score 1):

Для редактирования текстового файла, требующего изменения его размера, нет иного способа как создать новый текстовый файл. Конкретно для случая со звездочками можно открыть файл в режиме чтения-записи, читать каждый символ и если это звездочка, переписывать его каким-либо нечитаемым символом.

Comment: "Для редактирования текстового файла, требующего изменения его размера, нет иного способа как создать новый текстовый файл" ... Хренова (((

Comment: "Для редактирования текстового файла, требующего изменения его размера, нет иного способа как создать новый текстовый файл" - 
Ну, или считать файл в буфер = объему исходного файла, старый файл грохнуть и создать новый или поверх старого полностью переписать содержимое буфера.

Comment: Ну, в данном случае, требуется только удалять байты. Поэтому буфер записи м.б. небольшим и как бы скользить по файлу вслед за буфером чтения.

Answer (score 0):

например так:

```
char s[1111]; //исходная строка
char ans[1111]; // полученная строка
int c = 0; // количество символов в полученной строке

//Вставьте код: открытие 1.txt на чтение
scanf("%s", &s);
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
       if (s[i] != '*') 
              ans[c++] = s[i];
//Вставьте код:  закрытие файла 1.txt

//Вставьте код:  открытие 1.txt на запись
printf("%s", ans);
//Вставьте код:  закрытие файла 1.txt.
```

Comment: Нужна программа для работы со всеми txt файлами, разных размеров ... Например с размером 1 GB или больше.  этот код у тебя работать не будет

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream f("file.txt");
    ofstream f0("file.txt");
    char s[10];
    f >> s;
    f0 << s;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```